# Unable to locate Attribute with JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I need to validate if the attribute *acronym* of binUse is equal to *BinUseAcronym.FPAN.toString()*. I need access binUse.acronym

ProductBin

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "BIN_USE_ID", nullable = false)
private BinUse binUse;
```

BinUse

```
@Id
@Column
private Long id;
@Column
private String acronym;
```

My CriteriaQuery

```
ProductBin productBin = this.productBinRepository.findOne(new Specification<ProductBin>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ProductBin> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        List<Predicate> listPredicate = new ArrayList<>();
        listPredicate.add(cb.equal(root.get("start"), bin.getStart()));
        listPredicate.add(cb.equal(root.get("end"), bin.getEnd()));
        listPredicate.add(cb.equal(
            root.get("BinUse_.acronym"), BinUseAcronym.FPAN.toString())
        );

        return cb.and(listPredicate.toArray(new Predicate[listPredicate.size()]));
    }
});
```

I try to add the class name before attribute but I keep receiving a exception:

```
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [BinUse_.acronym] on this ManagedType [com.edenred.commons.domain.ProductBin];
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is `BinUse_.acronym` supposed to do? Is there a property named `BinUse_` in `ProductBin`? If you wanted to refer to the value of `ProductBin.binUse.acronym`, just use `root.join("binUse").get("acronym")`

Comment: @crizzis Exactly

Comment: @crizzis What's the difference between ```root.join("binUse").get("acronym")``` and ```root.get("binUse").get("acronym")```?

Comment: There is little difference in this case. `join` just makes it explicit that what is referenced here is a relationship (as opposed to a simple) attribute. Think of it as equivalent to the JPQL: `SELECT p FROM ProductBin p JOIN p.binUse b WHERE b ...` vs `SELECT p FROM ProductBin p WHERE p.binUse ...`